# md-chips not working with md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I am try to work on this snippet where an autocomplete is embedded in chips. But the item selected from autocomplete does not convert into chip.

The data from the auto complete is in the following manner:
`{name:"John Doe", id:"1"}`

Please advise where I am wrong.

Regards

Here is my code for Chips:

```
<md-chips ng-model="student_ex" 
    md-autocomplete-snap
    md-transform-chip="transformChip($chip)"
    md-require-match flex>
       <md-autocomplete flex
            md-selected-item="student"
            md-search-text="searchText"
            md-items="item in searchStudent(searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.name"
            placeholder="Search for a Student to Exclude">
                <span md-highlight-text="searchText">ID: {{ item.id }} | Name: {{ item.name }}</span>
       </md-autocomplete>
       <md-chip-template>
                <span>
                    <strong>{{$chip}}</strong><em></em>
                </span>
       </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

And this is my searchStudent and transformChip:

```
$scope.searchStudent = function (query) {
    if ((/^\d+$/.test(query))) {
        var results = query ? $scope.student_list.filter(
            function (name) {
                var regex = new RegExp(query,'gi');
                return name.id.match(regex);
            }
        ) : $scope.student_list;
    } else {
        var results = query ? $scope.student_list.filter(
            function (name) {
                var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
                var regex = new RegExp(lowercaseQuery,'gi');
                return name.name.match(regex);
            }
        ) : $scope.student_list;
    }
    return results;
};

$scope.transformChip = function (chip) {
    return {items:chip};
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add: it returns the error: `Error: this.items is undefined
MdChipsCtrl.prototype.appendChip@http://localhost/api/api/api/web/js/angular-material.js:20754:9`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialize the model, like this:

```
$scope.student_ex = [];
```

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.student_list = $scope.student_list = [{name:"John Doe", id:"1"}, {name:"Antipod", id:"2"}];
    $scope.student_ex = [];

    $scope.searchStudent = function (query) {
        if ((/^\d+$/.test(query))) {
            var results = query ? $scope.student_list.filter(
                function (name) {
                    var regex = new RegExp(query,'gi');
                    return name.id.match(regex);
                }
            ) : $scope.student_list;
        } else {
            var results = query ? $scope.student_list.filter(
                function (name) {
                    var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
                    var regex = new RegExp(lowercaseQuery,'gi');
                    return name.name.match(regex);
                }
            ) : $scope.student_list;
        }
        return results;
    };

    $scope.transformChip = function (chip) {
        return chip;
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-chips ng-model="student_ex" 
        md-autocomplete-snap
        md-transform-chip="transformChip($chip)"
        md-require-match flex>
           <md-autocomplete flex
                md-selected-item="student"
                md-search-text="searchText"
                md-items="item in searchStudent(searchText)"
                md-item-text="item.name"
                placeholder="Search for a Student to Exclude">
                    <span md-highlight-text="searchText">ID: {{ item.id }} | Name: {{ item.name }}</span>
           </md-autocomplete>
           <md-chip-template>
                    <span>
                        <strong>{{$chip.name}}</strong><em></em>
                    </span>
           </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
</div>
```

Comment: That was rather simple. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I would say the fix was simple, but it really took time to find it. I am glad it has helped.

Comment: I understand that. I wasted two hours on it before posting here. Hence my astonishment. :P Thanks for your time man! :D

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It should absolutely initialize an array if undefined... like every other component...